# Auto-complete Edit text android

Tags: android, autocomplete, android-edittext, textview

**I want to achieve the functionality of Autocomplete edit-text view but in slightly different way.**

In normal autocomplete textView it shows suggestions in the dropdown below for every element you enter, for every word you enter actually. but i am working on an application that actually has buttons that controls the text in the text view.

**What i need is**

When `Button-A` is clicked, my edit text should become a auto-complete edit text and the suggestions should start showing, but when i press `ENTER` or i press `Button-B` the auto complete feature should be removed. and so on. when i press `button-A` again, auto complete feature should re-appear

```
How can i achieve this?
```

**What i have tried uptil now**

I have actually tried to implement a auto-complete text view but i am unable to get this functionality out of it. I have an auto complete text view implemented, but it just show suggestions for every item we enter.

Comment: tried setting an adapter to null? or to an adapter with size == .0?

Comment: no, how can i do that?

Comment: i mean to say should i write an adapter for edit text?

Comment: set it to null first?

Answer (score 1):

You can use simple Autocomplete edit-text But when click on `Button-A` Enable autoComplete

and when click on `Button-B` disable autoComplete.

add this string to code:

```
private static final String[] COUNTRIES = new String[] {
    "Belgium", "France", "Italy", "Germany", "Spain"
};
```

click on `Button-B`:

```
edittext.setInputType(et.getInputType()| EditorInfo.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS |EditorInfo.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_FILTER);
```

click on `Button-A`:

```
AutoCompleteTextView textView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.actv_country);
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, COUNTRIES);
textView.setAdapter(adapter);
```